# Python importing two modules that have the same class name

Tags: python, class, import, module

I'm doing some image processing and have the need to import two modules, but those modules have same class name. Example:

```
from wand.image import Image  
from PIL import Image
```

The method(s) I'm using, unfortunately, are not contained in both, hence my need for the two modules. Currently my workaround to this problem is import the modules over and over again in a for loop, but this seems incorrect. Example:

```
for my_images in images:
   from wand.image import Image
   # run code for this module

   from PIL import Image
   # run code for this module
```

Is there a way I can 'rename' or call the class/method using a different name? Thanks.

Comment: You can use the `as` operator. e.g. `from PIL import Image as pil_image`, and then use `pil_image` in your code, instead of just `Image`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use, for example:

```
from wand.image import Image as Image_wand
from PIL import Image as Image_PIL
```

or any another different names with a help of `as`.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said you could use `as`.

Another possibility is importing the modules, then referencing the classes from there.

```
import wand
import PIL

wand.image.Image()
PIL.Image()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `as` keyword, which is meant for aliasing for situations like yours.

e.g.

```
from PIL import Image as PILImage
```

and then use `PILImage` in your code, instead of just `Image`.